# Responsive layout, box positions

Tags: css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm building a responsive site. The basic version has 2 columns, each column features a few boxes:

[image: desktop]

The 1 column layout shold look like this:

[image: mobile]

A naive approach for the one column version would be to place everything from second column under column one...but I can't do that. I need to be able to pick boxes from both columns and place them in custom order.
The only way I can think of is via box duplication and hiding for desktop/mobile. Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks, Michal

UPDATE: Since this seems to be Isotope (and similar libraries related), I've created a new post here: [Reordering boxes with Isotope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25301196/reordering-boxes-with-isotope?noredirect=1#comment39433840_25301196)

Comment: You could just float: left both columns. If the screen is to small, the second coloumn would just got down.

Comment: @web-tiki - I don't have a code yet, I'm asking about general principle

Comment: @Doodlebunch - I specifically added the letters to the screenshots so it's obvious that simple float:left doesn't provide custom ordering

Comment: I'm sorry, that was the point I didn't get.

Answer (score 1):

This is very nearly possible with some custom CSS. Unfortunately Bootstrap's default grid won't cater to your needs because items in either column have different heights.

[Here's a basic example on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/cufogunexijo/1/edit) (resize the output pane to see the elements stack).

[image: 2 column screenshot]

There's a lot of custom CSS here which is unfortunate, but it works.

```
.col-right, .col-left {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.col-left {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    height: 300px;
    background: teal;
}

.col-right {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    height: 200px;
    background: orange;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .col-left, .col-right {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

I've added a simple breakpoint at 767px for demonstration. If you're using Bootstrap's LESS, you'll want to replace this with `@screen-xs-max`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-left">A</div>
    <div class="col-right">D</div>
    <div class="col-left">B</div>
    <div class="col-right">E</div>
    <div class="col-right">F</div>
    <div class="col-left">C</div>
    <div class="col-right">G</div>
</div>
```

This works by using `float: left` or `float: right` for the left/right columns and `clear`ing only the float for that column. It's not perfect, but it's the closest you're going to get without using a JavaScript library like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Comment: Seems like a good direction, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adsq4ygt/. The mobile version is good, desktop has issues...E (on the right) needs pushing up, C (on the left) too. Achievable with pure CSS keeping the mobile version same?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should have a look into Isotope, seems to me it could help with what you are trying to achieve.

http://isotope.metafizzy.co

You could use Isotope and set up a one column layout.

You could also use Isotopes sorting to customise the order of your boxes on mobile.

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/sorting.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this one?

```
   <div style="float:left; width:50%; background: rgb(121, 82, 0);">
        <div>A</div>
        <div>B</div>
        <div>C</div>
        <div>D</div>
        <div>E</div>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; width:50%; background: rgb(0, 0, 255);">
        <div>F</div>
        <div>G</div>
        <div>H</div>
        <div>I</div>
    </div>
```