# Reordering boxes with Isotope

Tags: jquery-isotope

here's a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/adsq4ygt/

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        body {
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
        }
        .col-right, .col-left {
            width: 50%;
        }
        .col-left {
            float: left;
            clear: left;
            background: teal;
        }
        .col-right {
            float: right;
            clear: right;
            background: orange;
        }
        @media (max-width: 769px) {
            .col-left, .col-right {
                float: none;
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
        .a {
            height:300px;
        }
        .b {
            height: 150px;
        }
        .c {
            height:400px;
        }
        .d {
            height:150px
        }
        .e {
            height:250px
        }
        .f {
            height:350px
        }
        .f {
            height:450px
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-left a">A</div>
        <div class="col-right d">D</div>
        <div class="col-left b">B</div>
        <div class="col-right e">E</div>
        <div class="col-right f">F</div>
        <div class="col-left c">C</div>
        <div class="col-right g">G</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

with my custom layout. It's also responsive, the boxes just stack vertically. The pure CSS desktop version has issues - the empty spaces. I don't think I can get rid of them with pure CSS, so I wanted to use Isotope.

I've been playing with different settings but wasn't able to achieve that with Isotope. Can anyone help me with Isotope options that'd achieve this? You can also modify markup/CSS - as long as the mobile version looks the same as now it's not a problem

Thanks

Comment: Is this helpful: http://www.i-do-this.com/blog/using-jquery-isotope-for-masonry-in-fluid-layouts/57

Comment: Yeah, I've been fiddling with Isotope for a few hours but still I'm not able to achieve what I want. I thought someone might give me the HTML/JS needed